# How to file upload and view the datalist

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I insert the code;

HTML:

```
                <asp:Label ID="document" runat="server" Text="Document"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Label ID="upload" runat="server" Text="Upload Document"></asp:Label>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" multiple="true" Style="text-align: center;
                    margin-left: 50px;" Height="27px" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadFile" CommandName="Add" />

    <asp:DataList ID="datalist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="5" BorderWidth="25px"
        CellSpacing="2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False"
        Font-Underline="False" GridLines="Both">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        My Folder
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                        runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                        runat="server" OnClick="DeleteFile" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

VB:

```
Dim lsfilename As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("..\Fileupload\insert\"))
        Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
        Next
        datalist.DataSource = files
        datalist.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub UploadFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs((Server.MapPath("..\Fileupload\insert\") + name.Text))
    lsfilename = name.Text
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub
Protected Sub DownloadFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim filePath As String = CType(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument
    Response.ContentType = ContentType
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath)))
    Response.WriteFile(filePath)
    Response.End()
End Sub
Protected Sub DeleteFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim filePath As String = CType(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument
    File.Delete(filePath)
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    datalist.DataBind()
End Sub
```

But, its not display the file name and how to write the previous and next button code. I want only insert the 9 files after that its going to next page. Please any one help to me.

Thanks,

Comment: Please explain what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `datalist's` item template set the textbox `text` as below

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I inserted the text; but i got the error:       BC30201: Expression expected.   How to solve this problem. if any body help to me.                      Thanks,

Comment: I tried that updated code, i got the error:  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.                      Error Line is:Line 84:                         <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 'Value') %>"></asp:TextBox>         How to solved this error, i don't know, Please any one help to me.

Comment: No you didn't try the updated code in updated code the expression is changed `Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'` and your exception the is same as as older one.

Comment: If it helped you please mark it as answer so question can be closed.

Comment: I want to display the 9 files into the datalist other than goes to next page. how to do this, please help to me........